# Event to check quote for product on every page

Tags: cart, event-observer, quote

I am programmatically adding a product to cart *if* a certain coupon code is applied to cart.

I would like to check this on every page so that the product only shows up when the coupon is applied and no issues with cookies, etc.

What event can I observe for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `controller_action_predispatch`.
This event is dispatched for every page, before the action is executed.

Comment: or use the CatalogController if you're not comfortable with Observers :)

Comment: Thanks!  I used controller_action_predispatch and works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

In order to add an observer to an event on every page add this in config.xml of your module.

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <Namespace_ModuleName>
                <class>Namespace_ModuleName/observer</class>
                <method>Observer_action_name</method>
            </Namespace_ModuleName>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```